# Linear algebra and matrix kernels

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a set of vectors $v_i \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $i=1,...,m$ and I want to know if there exists a matrix $A \ne 0$ such that $v_i \in \operatorname{Ker}(A)$ for all $i$.

Now my approach is to show that in order for such an $A$ to exist, the $v_i$ must span a subspace of dimension less than $n$. And in order to prove that, is it sufficient to show that:
$$
v_i \cdot e_k = 0
$$
for some $k$ and all $i$?

Comment: Can you be more specific? For as it stands, the zero-matrix is a solution (i.e., just pick $A = 0_{n \times n}$) I'm pretty sure you want something different from this, but I don't know what it is.

Comment: I edited the question, I am looking for nontrivial matrices $A$

Comment: Yes. You need to make sure the set of $v_i$ spans $W\subsetneq V$ for otherwise the only linear map satisfying the specified conditions will be the trivial map. If $m<n$, you are guaranteed such a matrix will exist, since the vectors will indeed span $W\subsetneq V$. On the other hand, if $m=n$, you need to show that the set of $v_i$ is linearly dependent or in other words, that $\det M=0$ where $M$ is the matrix with $v_i$ as columns.

Answer (score 1):

1. The general claim is true: if $span\{v_1, \ldots, v_m\} \ne \Bbb R^n$, then there's a nonzero matrix $A$ with $v_i \in ker(A)$ for all $i$.
2. To prove that the span is not the whole space, you propose showing that there's a standard basis vector $e_k$ orthogonal to all vectors in your list. That approach does not work, as the example $v_1 = \pmatrix{1\\1}$ (the number of elements, $m$, is $1$ here) in $\Bbb R^2$ shows.

I think that this answers both your questions.

Comment: So how would I show $span\{v_1,...,v_m\} \subset \mathbb{R}^n$? We can assume that $m>n$ for this.

Comment: What??? This makes no sense at all. If the $v$-vectors are all in $\Bbb R^n$, then their span is, because ... because of every imaginable definition of span, and the fact that $\Bbb R^n$ is a vector space. Your original question didn't mention $m > n$, and it's pretty rude to add it after the fact, but if you really want that, then just make $v_2 = v_3 = v_1$ and you've got an example. If that makes you unhappy, try, in $\Bbb R^3$,  $v_1 = \pmatrix{1\\1\\2}, v_2 = \pmatrix{1\\1\\3}, v_3 = v_1 + v_2, v_4 = v_1 - v_2$.

Comment: Oh, wait. You're probably using $\subset$ to mean "proper subset." Sigh. Well, I can't prove that the span is a proper subset, because it's not always true. If it IS true, then there's a nontrivial $A$. If it's not true, then $A$ must be zero.